# Why is the trivial group a zero object for the category of groups, but the empty set isn't a zero object for the category of sets?

Tags: group-theory, category-theory

I understand that the zero ring can't be a zero object for the category of rings, because in that case the 'arrows' are ring homomorphisms which, by definition, but maintain the unit.

But in the category of sets, the 'arrows' are just functions between sets. So why isn't the empty set a terminal object (and hence a zero object)?

Comment: Because there is no function $X\to\emptyset$ when $X$ is an inhabited set.

Comment: Ok, and the same reasoning doesn't apply to the trivial group because the trivial group actually contains an element (i.e. the identity)? Thanks